# What is the Windows 10 Process to Gain access to other User account files?

Tags: windows, windows-10

Preface: Not a dos AdminCMD Expert!

As the Admin how do I view Pictures folder ECT.

In File explorer I seem to only see C drive folders of my old user account and Music...
But I'm not seeing pictures folder.

I'm lost as to accessing other files via new account!

Cannot utilize Gui in other profile user account.

From olde account only have Task manager and Admin CMD access! Meaning if a AdminCMD user group share command process exsits that would help! Does it?

Side note:
 Had Gui issue on other account /full account of problem can be viewed here  @ thread [Explorer.exe refreshing](https://superuser.com/questions/1503569/explorer-exe-refreshing/)

Comment: Can you include the folder path you've looked at unsuccessfully, maybe post a screenshot so we can help you out better?

Answer (score 0):

Default location to a users pictures folder (replace Username with your own): `C:\Users\Username\Documents\Pictures` or `C:\Users\Username\Pictures`. If you are trying to access another users files when you browse to the location above it will prompt for admin credentials or to get permissions. Nothing is stopping a user from storing pictures to another folder. Furthermore you can redirect 'Library' folders like that to another location. Might be best to use Explorer to access the user profile folder (location above) & simply search for pictures